How do you change the clickable region around a label in Java FX?
In Java FX, you can change the padding around a label with CSS. In doing so with negative values, you can remove some space between the border of the label and the text inside it, like the images below, where I add negative padding to the top border:


Before Padding



After Negative Top Padding

This is fine. My problem, though, is that doing this doesn't change the "clickable region" of the node. I reduced the padding at the top by 20 pixels in the images above, and as a result, the OnMouseEntered, OneMouseClicked, etc... events will all get triggered for the case of the second image even when my mouse is within 20 pixels above the second image's top border. Notably, pickOnBounds has no effect on this issue.
The question is - how do you change the area that event handlers listen for to be only the area with the border of a label/node?
Version of Java FX: 21

Provide a minimal reproducible example

Put it in a pane with padding applied to the pane.  Or use margin for panes that support it.

Moving the borders won't change the dimensions of the Node itself. If you want to get the contents closer to the edge of the Node, then play around with the "Padding" parameter.

As I mentioned, the padding parameter does not correct this problem. The extra layout is a good idea, but I don't know that it won't just add space between the top of the pane and the top of label, defeating the purpose. I'll post the requested example in an edit when I get the chance.

It's not entirely clear what your requirements are; if you want a border this is usually better implemented using "nested backgrounds", which will likely give you more control over the location of the border relative to the label's text without artificially changing the dimensions of the label.

My issue is that I can move that top border down with padding, no problem, background and border insets, no problem, but if I bind a listener to the label for when I want to click on it, the listener can still be tripped for a click above that border up to where the border had been before moving it down with the padding. I'll edit the question for clarification later, same as the requested example. I also found that Harlow Solid Italic as a font illustrates this issue much better than what I had.

@GeorgeEconomou it is often better to add additional info and clarifications as question edits instead of comments.  If desired you can also add a comment to notify another commenter that the question was edited and delete that notification comment later on when it is clear that the notification was received.

You keep talking about "border padding".  If you mean "border insets", then that is distinctly different from "padding" which determines the distance from the contents to the edge of the Region.

Yes, padding adds space around the node, while insets move the border with respect to the node’s edge. If you were to replicate what I demonstrated in CSS, you’d have -fx-padding: -20 0 0 0; -fx-border-insets: 20 0 0 0; (either one or both is the same, I tested). The problem is that despite any combination of those rules, listeners still trip for the mouse entering the 20 pixels above the top borderline. The expected behavior by my understanding is great when you add space, not when you want to remove it.

My computer needs to be repaired. I will just ask this question again in a more clear way later, and delete this question then.

As others have indicated, "making part of the label not clickable" is (almost certainly) not the correct approach here. Make the border the edge of the label and add space around the label in whatever the parent is.
